# Reducing size of Subfigure

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, resize

I have four sub figures put together (two by two) but I would like to make the top two subfigures smaller. How do I go up about doing this? This is what my current code looks like (see below) and my figures are pdfs that were cropped outside of LaTeX. I thought maybe trim might be the way to go but I'm not sure. Thank you in advance

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Alpha 25 -1.6 Cropped.pdf}
         \label{fig:Alpha}
     \end{subfigure}
     \quad
     %\hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{V 25 -1.6 Cropped.pdf}
         \label{fig:Forward Speed}
     \end{subfigure} \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pitch Angle 25 -1.6.pdf}
         \label{fig:theta}
     \end{subfigure}
     %\hfill
     \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pitch Rate 25 -1.6.pdf}
         \label{fig:q}
     \end{subfigure}
    \caption{$\alpha$, V, $\theta$ and $q$ bifurcation diagrams.}
    \label{fig:25 -1.6} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Try replacing `[width=\textwidth]` with `[width=\linewidth]`.

Comment: Doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: In this case try with `[width=0.48\textwidth]`.

Comment: That definitely made them small (maybe too small) but I now know what to tweak to make them smaller. One small problem though. Doing this seems to have stop what the placement specifier [t] was doing which I believe was making sure the tops of the side by side subfigures were aligned. Anyway to remedy this?

Comment: Personally, when I want to have control on the alignment of (sub)figures or (sub)tables, I use the `floatrow` package and its `(sub)floatrow` environments`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to your preamble and use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=t]` instead of `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]`.

Comment: Any news? You receive two answers, bot solve your problem. Now is time to select one of them for accepting (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer).

Comment: Apologies for the silence, there were all very helpful but I ended up using minipage instead of subfigure along with some aspects of each of the answers under this question. Thank you all for the assistance

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer or at least an upvote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the figures can be controlled by the `subfigure` argument.

Being the normal size of them equal to `textwidth`,  writing   `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}` will scale them to 0.3 of their original width. To center them insert a `hspace` equal to half of the remaining space (`0.4\textwidth` in this case).

You need to have  `keepaspectratio` in the `\includegraphics` to ...  well,  to keep the aspect ratio of the imported images while being expanded to `\textwidth`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption} %  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:Alpha}
    \end{subfigure}
%   \quad
    \hspace*{.20\textwidth} % half of the free horizontal space
%   \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:Forward Speed}
    \end{subfigure} \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:theta}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.02\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,  keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:q}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{$\alpha$, V, $\theta$ and $q$ bifurcation diagrams.}
    \label{fig:25 -1.6} 
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Reduced to `0.1\textwidth`. No problem with `[t]` apparent.

[image: b]

Answer (score 1):

- labeling of `subfigures` hasn't sense since you not have captions for them
- sub-images can be simple arrangement by use of `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \\
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    &   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
     \end{tabular}
\caption{$\alpha$, V, $\theta$ and $q$ bifurcation diagrams.}
\label{fig:25 -1.6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]